# Showing HTML content in Pentaho CDE Table Component

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am developing Dashboard using Pentaho Community edition (CDE dashboard). One of the requirement is to display the data in Table component. The source query returns three columns like Person Name, Popularity an Tweeter link. When query is passed to table component the column data under tweeter link is seen as plain text. Instead of text display, I need to showc the HTML contents for that url.

Can you suggest the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Method and you will get what you need.
http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.in/2014/07/hyperlink-for-table-columns-in-pentaho.html

Comment: Thanks for link. It is not the complete solution but it did gave me right direction to work on.